# Receiving a HTTP 500 Error while testing with jersey test framework

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey, mockito

I implemented a **REST** web service and want to test my implementation with jUnit test.

As I am using the **REST** reference framework *Jersey*, I want to use the provided test framework *JerseyTest*, but I get some strange behaviour:

If my resource creates a response containing a String, every thing works fine (see test case *responseCodeIs404IfGetForNotExistingGuiTag()*).
The problem occures as soon as my response contains a pojo (see test case *responseCodeIs200IfGetForExistingGuiTag()*). I don't receive the expected 200 response code, but a 500 'Internal Server Error'. If I test the whole interface "by hand" every thing works fine. So I assume I need to configure the test framework in some way, but I couldn't figure out how.

I took [this](https://github.com/Robert-Leggett/jersey_restful_webservice) implementation as template.

I use Jersey 2.0 (as it is currently running on my glassfish 4.0 (no opportunity to update this)), Mockito as mocking framework and Jackson as JSON framwork.

I hope you guys can help me. If you need some more information please let me know it.

**GuiTagResource.java**

```
@Path("/char")
public class GuiTagResource {

    private GuiTagRepository guiTagRepo;

    @Inject
    public void setGuiTagRepo(GuiTagRepository guiTagRepo) {
        this.guiTagRepo = guiTagRepo;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response getGuiTagById(@PathParam("id") int guiTagNo) {

        Optional<GuiTag> guiTag = guiTagRepo.getCharGuiTagById(guiTagNo);

        Response response;

        if (!guiTag.isPresent()) {
            //This case works fine
            response = Response.status(404).entity("GuiTag with id " + Integer.toString(guiTagNo) + " was not found.")
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        } else {
            //This case produces a 404 Error
            CharacteristicGuiTag guiTagTo = fromEntity((CharacteristicGuiTagEntity) guiTag.get());
            response = Response.status(200).entity(guiTagTo).build();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

**GuiTagResourceTest.java**

```
public class GuiTagResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Mock
    private GuiTagRepository repoMock;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(GuiTagResource.class);
        config.register(new InjectableProvider());

        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void responseCodeIs404IfGetForNotExistingGuiTag() {

        when(repoMock.getCharGuiTagById(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(absent());

        Response response = target("char/5").request().get();

        //Passes -> response code is 404
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(404));
    }

    @Test
    public void responseCodeIs200IfGetForExistingGuiTag() {

        Optional<GuiTag> compareTag = getGuiTagMock();
        CharacteristicGuiTag pojo = fromEntity((CharacteristicGuiTagEntity)     compareTag.get());

        when(repoMock.getCharGuiTagById(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(compareTag);

        Response response = target("char/5").request().get();

        CharacteristicGuiTag responsePojo = response.readEntity(CharacteristicGuiTag.class);

        //Doesn't pass as response is 500?
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
    }

    private Optional<GuiTag> getAbsentMock() {
        //returns a Optional.absent() to fake a failed db get.
    }

    private Optional<CharacteristicGuiTagEntity> getCharGuiTagMock() {
        //returns a guiTag
    }

    class InjectableProvider extends AbstractBinder implements Factory<GuiTagRepository> {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindFactory(this).to(GuiTagRepository.class).in(Singleton.class);
        }

        public GuiTagRepository provide() {
            return repoMock;
        }

        public void dispose(GuiTagRepository service) {
            repoMock = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**The console Logs**

```
Nov 21, 2014 12:53:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
Nov 21, 2014 12:53:27 PM     org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer start
INFO: Starting GrizzlyTestContainer...
Nov 21, 2014 12:53:27 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998]
Nov 21, 2014 12:53:27 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.

Nov 21, 2014 12:53:28 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * LoggingFilter - Request received on thread main
1 > GET http://localhost:9998/char/5

Nov 21, 2014 12:53:28 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Nov 21, 2014 12:53:28 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread main
2 < 500
2 < Date: Fri, 21 Nov 2014 11:53:28 GMT
2 < Content-Length: 0
2 < Connection: close
```

Comment: Could it be because you are using `getGuiTagMock()` in the test method `responseCodeIs200IfGetForExistingGuiTag()` instead of `getCharGuiTagMock()`?

Comment: Are there any other logs(that might have a stacktrace)?

Comment: Ah I just figured it out (after research for almost a day). I did have the library `jersey-media-moxy.jar` included to my build path. This lib caused an error, even if it was not used. Thanks Priyesh for taking your time look over my code and I'm sorry I wasted it.